# Symfony 4 : call a vendor (with no namespaces) installed with composer

Tags: php, controller, composer-php, symfony4, vendor

I'm learning SF4, composer etc... and I'm not a php expert :)

I have a SF 4 project where I want to integrate this : 
https://github.com/etienne-gauvin/api-allocine-helper

So I installed it with composer which created the matching vendor dir.

Outside SF it's working fine, I'm calling the helper with require_once and then I'm able to use the classes included in the helper.

The thing is I don't know how to use it from my SF controller.

So I guess there are 2 ways of doing it but I don't know how and I'd like to do it the "right"(recommended) way :

1. I could use it like I'm doing outside SF but I don't know how to require the helper from my controller. I think this might not be very "clean".
2. I think a best method could be to add namespaces to this vendor (as they doesn't exist at the moment) to call classes directly from the controller. I saw that it's possible to configure namespace with psr-4 in the composer.json of that vendor.

Can someone provide me advices and guide me to achieve this please ?
Thanks in advance
Fab.

**EDIT :** 
Well I think I found, I didn't know but it seems I'm able to use the 3 classes I needed symply with "Use classname" in my controller and now it's working. Thanks to PhpStorm who auto suggested me both classes when i typed "Use" in my controller :)